# try to develop a own Extension, it can not run on xampp. the own dll was compiled vs2012

Tags: php

when I start the xampp apache server it shows a warning:

```
PHP starup:  myext :  Unable to initialize module Module  compiled with build ID=API20131226 ,TS
PHP compiled with build ID=API20131226 ,TS,VC11
```

These options need to match

but I was compiled the project with `vs2012`

my xampp version is `xampp-win32-5.6.3`

my php src code was `5.6.3 vc11`

Answer (score 0):

add  '#define PHP_COMPILER_IF "VC11"' at the cpp beginning